# How to read output value from stored procedure in c#?

Tags: stored-procedures

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_searchupdate
(
@id int,
@id_student int,
@output varchar(50) output,
@Tamil Varchar (100),
@English varchar (50),
@Maths Varchar (50),
@Science Varchar (50),
@SocialScience Varchar (50) 
)

AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM studentresult WHERE id=@id) 
BEGIN
UPDATE studentresult SET Tamil = @Tamil,English = @English, Maths = @Maths,Science = @Science,SocialScience = @SocialScience WHERE id = @id
SET @output='Updated'
RETURN
END
Else
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM student WHERE id=@id_student)
SET @output='EXIST'
RETURN
BEGIN
INSERT into studentresult (id_student,Tamil,English,Maths,Science,SocialScience) values (@id_student,@Tamil,@English,@Maths,@Science,@SocialScience)
SET @output='Inserted'
RETURN
END
END
```

If inserted data in front-end it need to shows 'inserted' or update means 'updated' or else 'exist'.

But for the above query didn't show notification message.

May i know, what my mistake in my code?

Can anyone guide me, I'M new stored procedure and .net.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It's rather unclear exactly what you are trying to achieve - why would you only insert into the studentresult record if the student record did NOT exist? Anyway, currently if no studentresult record exists then the procedure will always return after the check for the student record. There is no BEGIN...END after the IF EXISTS so only the first statement after the IF will be dependent on the result. Try:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_searchupdate
(
@id int,
@id_student int,
@output varchar(50) output,
@Tamil Varchar (100),
@English varchar (50),
@Maths Varchar (50),
@Science Varchar (50),
@SocialScience Varchar (50) 
)

AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM studentresult WHERE id=@id) 
BEGIN
UPDATE studentresult SET Tamil = @Tamil,English = @English, Maths =     @Maths,Science = @Science,SocialScience = @SocialScience WHERE id = @id
SET @output='Updated'
END
Else
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM student WHERE id=@id_student)
BEGIN
    SET @output='EXIST'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT into studentresult (id_student,Tamil,English,Maths,Science,SocialScience) values (@id_student,@Tamil,@English,@Maths,@Science,@SocialScience)
    SET @output='Inserted'
END
END

RETURN
END
```